# Filter not working in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a question about filtering in ng-repeat.

Here is template code:

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:personFilter">
    <span>{{friend.name}}</span>
    <span>{{friend.phone}}</span>
    <span>{{friend.items | GetItemsTitels}}</span>
</li>
</lang-html>
```

where GetItemsTitels return some string. 
**[Here is live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RXmpT/)**

Why doenst personFilter working on last column which shows stirng returned from GetItemsTitels filter? If jsfiddle if you type 'aa' in filter your don't get any result.
Is it because filter for this column is already assigned and that is why personFilter doesn't apply for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filter on `ng-repeat` will only take into account what is *in* the object. Not what might be  displayed while the loop is running. You could however populate `friends` with the real data and then the filter should work.

Usage:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | injectItemTitles:'itemTitles' | filter:personFilter">
    <span>{{friend.name}}</span>
    <span>{{friend.phone}}</span>
    <span>{{friend.itemTitles.join(', ')}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iciyoq/2/

There might be one problem with this approach, as it whould *inject* the item titels on each *digest cycle*. So it could be better to apply the `injectItemTitles`-filter in the controller on large datasets.

---

Full code:

```
(function (app, ng) {
  'use strict';

  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.friends = [{
      name: 'John',
      phone: '555-1276',
      items : ['id0', 'id1']
    }, {
      name: 'Mary',
      phone: '800-BIG-MARY',
      items : ['id1', 'id2']
    }, {
      name: 'Mike',
      phone: '555-4321',
      items : ['id2', 'id3']
    }, {
      name: 'Adam',
      phone: '555-5678',
      items : ['id3', 'id4']
    }, {
      name: 'Julie',
      phone: '555-8765',
      items : ['id4', 'id5']
    }];
  }]);

  app.filter('injectItemTitles', ['AllItems', 'getItemTitlesFilter', function(AllItems, getItemTitlesFilter) {
    return function(friends, prop){
      return friends.map(function(friend) {
        friend[prop] = getItemTitlesFilter(friend.items);
        return friend;
      });
    };
  }]);

  app.filter('getItemTitles', ['AllItems', function(AllItems){
    return function(items){
      return items.map(function (id) {
        return AllItems[id];
      });
    };
  }]);

  app.service('AllItems', function(){
    return {
      'id0' : 'aaa',
      'id1' : 'aab',
      'id2' : 'aba',
      'id3' : 'abb',
      'id4' : 'baa',
      'id5' : 'bab',
      'id6' : 'bba',
      'id7' : 'bbb'
    };
  });
}(angular.module('app', []), angular));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solution saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 6):

From what I understand:

Filters only work on "array" type, not "object" type.

given:

```
var friends={'a':'april','b':'bob'};

<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:personFilter">
<!-- personFilter will not run -->


var friends=[{code:'a',name:'april'},{code:'b',name:'bob'}];
personFilter=function(item){
    return item.code !== personModel
}

<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:personFilter">
<!-- will filter -->
```

Answer (score 1):

if you type 'aa' in filter your don't get any result because it will filter this 'aa' in friends list where 'aa' is not exists. As there are ids in items array which will again filters and returns string from all items. So whatever you type in text box will be filter from friends list only. If you still want to achieve this same thing then you have to modify you friends JSON.

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:personFilter">
<span>{{friend.name}}</span>
<span>{{friend.phone}}</span>
<span>{{friend.items | GetItemsTitels}}</span>
</li>
```

Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/RXmpT/3/